# pm2 for Ruby or Sinatra apps?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I currently use `pm2` to manage my node processes. I have run into a situation where I need to run a Sinatra server, but I don't know how to keep it alive.

Is there a `pm2` equivalent to host Ruby scripts or Sinatra apps?

Comment: I guess something like Phusion Passenger should do the job.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the PM2 Equivalent for ruby is... PM2. It allows you to choose your interpreter and [start *any* process type](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#start-any-process-type). The docs that I linked to even have an example for how to set start a Ruby process.

From the Docs:

> To run a non-JS interpreter you must set `exec_mode` to `fork_mode` and `exec_interpreter` to your interpreter of choice. For example:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"       : "bash-worker",
    "script"     : "./a-bash-script",
    "exec_interpreter": "bash",
    "exec_mode"  : "fork_mode"
  }, {
    "name"       : "ruby-worker",
    "script"     : "./some-ruby-script",
    "exec_interpreter": "ruby",
    "exec_mode"  : "fork_mode"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come from the node world and love pm2, foreman is pretty close for running ruby apps https://github.com/ddollar/foreman.  Foreman can kick off all of the services a given application relies on with one command.  It also can handle concurrency of your application and services.